# WordPress body_class() not adding CSS classes

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently I have been working on creating my first wordpress theme. However, when I was trying to add classes to body tag using PHP, the Chrome inspector shows that no classes have been added at all.

1. I have tried to move the body_class() PHP line out of the tag, and the appropriate class="(some classes)" loaded up successfully, but when the tag include the PHP scripts, no classes were added.
2. Manually adding classes inside the body tag in header.php does not work as well.

Is there any solution? Because my header.php should be following the right logic.

A link to my files:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h9YvmYEQYiHWI-N0lkelAUbVbEQwTelz

Comment: Is there any chance of getting the whole theme as you have it now as a zip file? if so, please share via drive.

Comment: I have checked your code, It's working fine here. Is there any console error?

Comment: I have added the zip file on the drive @CesarCorrechel.

Comment: When I use F12 inspector to check the classes of body on my local WordPress, the classes still did not exist @Sarbaz

Comment: May be you are changing in another theme, Please remove your whole code from `header.php`, then check that's changes effected in the site or not. If the theme is correct maybe the issue for caching. your code is perfect... :)

Comment: @Sarbaz It worked after clearing the cache of my browser. Thank you for reviewing my issue :)

Comment: @Mr.Benson Welcome. Always use `ctrl + shift + R` or `ctrl + F5` for page refresh (I think in MAC OS `cmd + shift + R`). It will more helpful for caching problem.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
/** 
* Adds custom classes to the array of body classes. 
*
* @param array $classes Classes for the body element. 
* @return array 
*/ 
 function White_theme_body_classes( $classes ) {
    // Adds a class of group-blog to blogs with more than 1 published author.
    if ( is_multi_author() ) {
        $classes[] = 'group-blog';
    }

    // Adds a class of hfeed to non-singular pages.
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        $classes[] = 'hfeed';
    }

    return $classes;
 } 
add_filter( 'body_class', 'White_theme_body_classes' );
```

and in header.php add this code

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Tried pasting the functions in functions.php but it is not fixing the issue.

Comment: send  header.php and functions.php to show full code and can help you